# React-native BleManager.write() don't work

Tags: react-native, react-native-ble-manager

I need a helping hand please. I use Ble_Manager in React-native, I receive the data from but I have a problem sending it.

```
const sendMessage = async (
  selectedDevice,
  isConnected,
  Buffer,
  messageToSend,
  BleManager,
  serviceid,
  caracid,
) => {
  if (selectedDevice && isConnected) {
    sendLog('messageToSend: ' + messageToSend);
    try {
      let buffer = Buffer.from(messageToSend);
      sendLog('buffer: ' + buffer);
      BleManager.write(
        selectedDevice.id,
        serviceid,
        caracid,
        buffer.toJSON().data,
      )
        .then(() => {
          sendLog('Write: ' + buffer.toJSON().data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          sendLog('error: ' + error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      sendLog('Error:' + error);
    }
  }
};
```

You can see the sendLog() method I use to log on my server. the first two logs arrive in real time, but from BleManager.write(), the logs do not arrive or a "Write" log arrives 1 minute or more later. In any case, no error logs.
I didn't find a solution in the existing comments.
When I test my hardware with nRFConnect, everything goes well, I receive and I can send data normally.

I would like to understand why this 'write' is malfunctioning?
Thank you for your attention.